# How can I iterate over a large Java List of Integers in less time?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

```
int[] records = job.getTargetSearchIDs();
topology.applyMatcherSearchWeight(records);
int[] mIDs = topology.getMatcherIds();
SystemResponse[] sysResponse = new SystemResponse[mIDs.length];
Map<Integer, SearchCommand> mrCmdsMap = new HashMap<Integer, SearchCommand>();
```

The length of mIDs is 250 and the length of records is 7.5 million integers. I want this loop to run in less than 3 seconds on a server with an 8-core Intel Xeon X5355 processor, 64-bit Linux (Ubuntu) and 32-bit Java.

```
for (long mID : mIDs) {
  List<Integer> recIDsToMatch = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  Matcher matcher = topology.getMatcherById(mID);

  for (long record : records) {
    if (matcher.getRange().isInRange(record))
      recIDsToMatch.add(record);
  }

  if (recIDsToMatch.size() > 0) {
    SearchCommand command = new SearchCommand(job.getMatchParameters(), 
      job.getRequestType(),
      job.getId(),
      job.getMatchParameters().getEngineProperties(),
      recIDsToMatch);

    command.setTimeout(searchTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mrCmdsMap.put(mID, command);
  }
}
```

What improvements come to mind when *you* read this code snippet? What data structure and/or algorithm improvements could be made?

Comment: Where are you today, how long does it take?

Comment: 40m records by mID or 40m records overall?

Comment: You should really reduce your code to the minimum relevant lines, rather than copy-pasting in a whole chunk.

Comment: There is any number of ways this could be optimised. I suggest you profile the application to determine why it is taking so long. Can you show us where you "iterate on a large range of integers"? 1000 is not large.

Comment: Sorry I was late for clarifying the problem. Right now the number of mIDs is 250 and the number of records is about 7,500,000. I takes 15 seconds for making the desired map(mrCmdsMap).

Answer (score 3):

If `isInRange()` actually checks whether the given integer is in a particular range, perhaps it would be better to put records into a data structure that performs this operation in more efficient way.

For example, try to put records into `TreeSet` and then use `subSet` to find records in the range.

Another way is to build something like `TreeMap<Integer, List<Matcher>>` where value is a list of `Matcher`s that cover a range between the current key and the following key. It can be even better, because number of `Matcher`s is less than number of records.

Comment: +1 Excellent idea to use subSet - it could reduce the time by a whole O(n)

Answer (score 2):

If you have large datasets and want speed and simplicity, consider using a text search engine like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html), which can index millions of documents and retrieve hits using quite complex matching parameters in a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

One single loop doesn't take that advantage of multi-core... it would be better if you could break this loop iteration in subsets, creating threads.

For example: divide your array in 6 pieces, one thread for each piece.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be no data dependency between each iteration of the outer loop, so you can and should parallelize it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over some set (and not search for an element within a set), that means that you will be running in at least ***O***[n] time complexity (i.e. linear time complexity), you also have a nested for loop, which brings your time complexity up to ***O***[n^2] time complexity (i.e. Quadratic time complexity).

Check to make sure you are not performing any surplus operations within the loop, and if possible move as much as possible outside of the loop (any initialization etc.)

If you just want to iterate through the set and then iterate through the member subset of that element of the set, then there is not much you can do that you have not done.

Answer (score 0):

You have left us to guess at the data structures underlying the problem, but there are three possibilities:

1. You are doing something that actually requires going through 40 billion records in 3 seconds (13G records/second).  I don't think your memory system can handle this bandwidth; you need more hardware if this is truly the case.  (But I bet it's not.)
2. You are simply looking to see if one number is in a set of 40 million ranges, and most numbers are not in that range.  You then want an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).  You can find a variety of implementations floating around; unfortunately, neither Apache Commons nor Guava has it.
3. You are simply looking to see which numbers out of 40 million are in 1000 different ranges.  Sort the 40 million numbers (once), then binary search to the endpoints of the range (for each range).  Everything in between is in.

If 2. or 3. describe your problem, it should take only a fraction of a second on a single core.